# How do I copy a file into my WAR based on profile?

Tags: gradle, properties-file, profiles

I’m using Gradle 2.7 on Mac Yosemite. I have the following files:

```
src/main/environment/dev/context.xml
src/main/environment/qa/context.xml
src/main/environment/prod/context.xml
```

What I would like is if I run a build `gradle -Pqa build`, the appropriate `context.xml` file above is copied into my `WAR` (into the WEB-INF/classes directory is fine). How do I set this up with gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're many ways of solving the problem. You can configure `sourceSets`, or `include` or `exclude` particular resources when building `war` file. You can also have single `context.xml` and perform resource filtering with `ReplaceTokens` filter.

I've chosen `sourceSets`:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

ext.env = project.hasProperty('env') ? project.env : 'dev'

sourceSets {
   main {
      resources {
         srcDir "src/main/environment/$env"
      }
   }
}
```

The trick is to include/process only the `env` being passed. If no `env` is passed `dev` will be picked for further processing. Have a look a the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33373744).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do that using the environment variable. Have the system properties in a file. Read them in the build.gradle and based on it include the context.xml into the war.

Comment: Having trouble with "Have the system properties in a file. ".  Please provide an example as to what I need to add to my build.gradle file to make this possible.